# Volume is correctly applying changes to files inside container. But creating new routes in local files are only resulting in error status 404

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops, prisma

**Question:**

This project is using express.js with node, prisma ORM and mysql database.

I have a backend Dockerfile and a docker-compose.yml file. The connection to the database is working and the volume is applying changes to container files. However, changing a route name in the express on index.ts only results in a 404 error. How can I fix this issue?

**This is the backend dockerfile**

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["bash", "-c", "npx prisma generate && npx prisma migrate deploy --schema=./schema.prisma && npm run dev"]
```

**This one is docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./Backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=#######################
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./Backend:/app
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=#####
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./Frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    environment:
      - VITE_API_URL=http://backend:3000
    volumes:
      - './Frontend:/app'

volumes:
  mysql_data:
```

To summarize:

- The connection to db is working
- Volume is applying changes to container files; I checked accessing index.ts inside container and sent `cat index.ts` to confirm
- Changing a route name localy from `/test` to `/test1` and using thunder client to make a request to this route only results in a status error 404.

the expected:

- On changing index.ts file localy, it updates the index.ts on the container trought volume, allowing me to create or update new routes on express without needing to restart all containers.